# How to remove whitespace between the image and the content below it?

Tags: html, css

There is some whitespace between the image and the content below it. I have tried using `body{background-color:black;}`, but that overwrites my color gradient on the lower part. I have not tried using something like nowrap, I'm not sure how to use it properly.

Below is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
{% load static %}
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'TSAWeb_App/contact.css' %}">
</head>

<body>
<div class = "ContactUs">
    <img src = "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/38/e9/9f/38e99f0083d07f6ac1df75b6bbb0fbf2.jpg" width = "100%">
    <div class = "w3-display-bottommiddle w3-container w3-text-white w3-padding-32 w3-hide-small"
            style = "white-space:nowrap">
        <h1 style = "text-align:center"><b>Our Socials</b></h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class = "MainBody">
    <p style = "text-align: center">
        <b>Find us at...</b>
    </p>

    <br>

    <div class = "Contacts">

        <figure class = "Insta">
            <a href = "https://www.instagram.com/dulles.tsa/">
                <img src = "https://www.freepnglogos.com/uploads/instagram-logos-png-images-free-download-2.png"
                        width = "50%" height = "50%">
                <figcaption>Instagram</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class = "Gmail">
            <a href = "mailto:dulles.tsa@gmail.com">
                <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/New_Logo_Gmail.svg"
                        width = "50%" height = "50%">
                <figcaption>Gmail</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class = "Discord">
            <a href = "https://discord.gg/uYFVqsy">
                <img src = "https://www.rust-evolution.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/discord-icon-template-9.png"
                        width = "50%" height = "50%">
                <figcaption>Discord</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class = "Twitter">
            <a href = "localhost:8000/contact">
                <img src = "http://assets.stickpng.com/images/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c53e.png"
                        width = "50%" height = "50%">
                <figcaption>Twitter</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

        <figure class = "Remind">
            <a href = "localhost:8000/contact">
                <img src = "https://www.pngkit.com/png/full/97-972295_remind-logo-blue.png"
                        width = "50%" height = "50%">
                <figcaption>Remind</figcaption>
            </a>
        </figure>

    </div>
</div>

</body>

{% endblock %}
```

And here is my existing CSS:

```
h1{
padding-bottom:125px;

}

p{
font-size:20px;
}

.Contacts {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.Contacts figure {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.MainBody{
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
color:white;
}

a{
color:white;
}
```

Comment: Please see how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using the relevant code so that we can see what is happening and be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's for the title **Our Socials** it's cause of the margins, reset the margin to 0, one recommendation that i see everywhere it's reset to 0 all margin because the browser gives you a margin.

Comment: Thanks, that helped I ended up doing ```*{margin:0}``` to apply the margin to the entire page.